# Sum in excel using a column as criteria

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula which will calculate the sum using a whole column as criteria

[image: sample cells]

In the above picture I want to sum the values in column B where in column A matches with the values of column D. The correct result will be 80 (sum of A,B & E)

Answer (score 1):

For a single cell formula, you could use the array formula `=SUMPRODUCT(values*COUNTIF(conditions,tags))`.

For your particular example, type `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B7*COUNTIF(D2:D4,A2:A7))` where you want the result and enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.